# How to make a stacked bar chart which has two categorises on the x-axis?

Tags: python

I am trying to create a stacked bar chart which has two categories on the x-axis, in this case, I want it by the group and then by year.

I am currently using Python 3 in PyCharm. I have created a mock-up in excel for what I am aiming to do.

If I use my example code in Excel and create a pivot chart I can create the exact graph I am looking for. I've put the chart and the example data from Excel on Google sheets so you can have a look:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jov0DwcMA8wUFXLSo88b-MfzfRI-BaOQF8PVjzogA0o/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you save your data to a `csv` file named `tmp.csv` (export to `csv` in Excel), then this script can construct a graph you want

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 

tmp = pd.read_csv('tmp.csv')
tmp_small = tmp.drop(['Group', 'Year'], axis=1)
year = tmp.loc[:, 'Year'].values
group = tmp.loc[:, 'Group'].values[[0, 2, 4]]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 6))
palette = ['r', 'g', 'b']

for ind in range(6):
    tmp_values = tmp_small.iloc[ind].values
    for count, item in enumerate(tmp_values):
        offset = np.sum(tmp_values[:count]) if count > 0 else 0
        ax.bar(x=ind, width=0.5, height=item, bottom=offset, color=palette[count])
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(len(year)))
ax.set_xticklabels(year)

ax.set_xlim(-1, 6.5)
ax.text(0.3, -10, group[0])
ax.text(2.3, -10, group[1])
ax.text(4.3, -10, group[2])
```

The output figure is

[image: figure]

Comment: @RK-Johns any questions?

Comment: Hello, appreciate the reply. My problem isn't so much the creation of a stacked bar chart but in the creation of a stacked bar chart which has a group and a subgroup. In my example I use group and year, so each group would be positioned on the x-axis, and then would have a stacked for each year - i.e. 2018 and 2019, and then have a x-axis label for the group these two bars belong to.

Comment: @RK-Johns Hello, I have modified my answer, you can check it now.

Comment: That's it mate. The ax.text part is what I needed, I should be able to add this to my code!